# Recent developments in interest rate modelling

Tags: interest-rates, reference-request

[Brigo and Mercurio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540221492) published the 2nd edition of their (classic? definitive?) book on interest rate models in 2006. Have there been any major theoretical developments since then? Has anyone published a book or paper that would bring me up-to-date?

In particular, have the Roger's potential approach ([link](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-9965.00029)) or the Markov functional approach of Hunt, Kennedy and Plesser ([link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=49240)) gained any traction? B&M mention them only in short sections in the appendices.

Comment: I think the biggest development has been the shift from LIBOR (London Inter-Bank Offered Rate) to SOFR (Secured Overnight Financing Rate).